# Why "Impossible constraint" with a typed 8-bit constant but not with an equivalent #define?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, avr-gcc

I am getting an error message about an impossible constraint using an 8-bit typed constant that I flag with constraint `"M"` in my inline assembly code for AVR 8-bit micro-controllers such as ATtiny1634 or ATmega328:

```
static const uint8_t tail_mask = (uint8_t)((rx1::queue_length-1) << \
    rx1::queue_length_bits) & 0xFF;

asm(
    ...
    "andi r30, %0\n\t"
    ...
:
: "M" (tail_mask)
);
```

> **warning**: asm operand 1 probably doesn't match constraints

Here `rx1` is a class name and both `queue_length` and `queue_length_bits` are `static const uint8_t` class constants. I can use `"O"`, `"N"`, no way. Using `static`, `int8_t` or not makes no difference.

If I replace the `static const uint8_t` definition above with a `#define`, the error message vanishes!

```
#define tail_mask ((rx1::queue_length-1) << rx1::queue_length_bits)

asm(
    ...
    "andi r30, %0\n\t"
    ...
:
: "M" (tail_mask)
);
```

Compiles fine!

That bugs me. Why does using an enforced 8-bit unsigned constant produce an error message over a constraint that forces it to be... an 8-bit unsigned constant?

For the record I'm using `avr-gcc` version **7.1.0**.

Comment: What happens if you define tail_mask as int32_t or uint32_t? Maybe the ruls for such constraints is you must pass a 32bit integer to express the range no matter what the costrained range is?

Comment: @stijn Gosh! you're right! I didn't have to use a 32-bit integer though, just an `unsigned` plain and simple, error gone. Thanks a lot for the hunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed to the constraint should probably be a 32 bit integer here. Which is what you get when you use the #define as it gets promoted to the expected type silently. Likewise using int or unsigned for your tail_mask value will be ok. Weird thing is I went through several versions of the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) but found no trace of evidence that the M constraint argument cannot be an uint8_t or similar.

Comment: Ah! I'm glad I hit a not no-brainer here ;-). The documentation is a bit scarce on that topic indeed. Thanks a lot again for the hint for I would never have thought of that on my own.